# CMMotion Manager gyroscope and accelerometer update intervals are wrong?

Tags: objective-c, accelerometer, gyroscope, cmmotionmanager

I'm trying to make an app that collects accelerometer and gyroscope updates at a given interval. The interval is the same for both the accelerometer and gyroscope so I am expecting the data from both to align. However using the CMMotionManger, the accelerometer and gyroscope data don't update perfectly at the given interval (I want 20 updates per second, and it ranges from 15-20) and the number of accelerometer points and gyroscope points are inconsistent despite them having the same update intervals. This is my code for starting the data collection:

```
- (void)startDataCollect {
    CMMotionManager *motionManager = [MainViewController sharedCMMotionManager];
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0/20.0;
    motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 1.0/20.0;
    acc_data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    gyro_data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    time_stamp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                    withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                        [self recordAccelerometer:accelerometerData.acceleration];
                                    }];
    [motionManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                           withHandler:^(CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error) {
                               [self recordGyroscope:gyroData.rotationRate];
                           }];
```

}

The handler methods just put the data into arrays which store the data until it is written onto files. The last time I tested the app I got 240 accelerometer data points and 366 gyroscope data points. Why is there a huge difference in the number of collected points if the intervals are the same? And why is the number of data points per second not consistent with the provided time interval?